# How to extract multiple substrings within speech marks using regex in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a Python script that takes an archived chat from Facebook Messenger (given as a json) and reformats it into text, for the purposes of archiving a couple of years of D&D roleplay. I'd therefore like to be able to separate out any of what is considered to be a character 'speaking' from what is considered to be a character's actions, so different formatting can be applied to them. This is problematic, since the chat was never designed for this purpose, so both " and ' have been used to delineate speech.

When read into Python, the messenger json file becomes a dictionary object. I'm currently looping through each message in the dictionary and trying to find all occurrences of speech in the 'content' key of each message (as there may be multiple bits of speech in each message), and print them all. I'm currently trying to do this with Python's RE `findall` function:

```py
for msg in msgs["messages"]:
    content = msg["content"]
    singlecheck = r"\s\'(.*?)\'\s"
    doublecheck = r'\"(.*?)\"'
    print(re.findall(f"{doublecheck}|{singlecheck}", content))
```

This is currently catching most of the speech in a given json file, but it is limited by a) messages that have more than one instance of speech, as despite calling `findall` it seems to only find the first; and b) words that are abbreviated with apostrophes at the start or end, such as 'aven't or missin'.

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: In order to get a desired output from your pattern you need to provide some input data.

Comment: There is no realistic way to differentiate `'aven't` from `'Yes, thats a banana'`